# onchange function is not working ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am new in ajax please help me.
First i am using a ajax pagination for display data and after that adding a filter in that data.my ajax pagination is working fine but filter not working properly.

```
<select name="profession" id="profession" class="form-control" style="width: 222px;"       onchange="search_author(this.value,'p_author'),loadData('',this.value)">

$(document).ready(function(){
            function loading_show(){
                $('#loading').html("<img src='img/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
            }
            function loading_hide(){
                $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
            }                
            function loadData(page,profess){

                loading_show();                    
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "load_data.php",
                    data: {page:page ,
                           prof:profess
                           },
                       async: true,
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                        {
                            loading_hide();
                            $("#container").html(msg);
                        });
                    }
                });
               alert(page)  ; // working
               alert(profess)  ; //not working
            }
            loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
            $('#container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
                var page = $(this).attr('p');
                loadData(page);

            });           
            $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
                var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                    loadData(page);
                }else{
                    alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                    $('.goto').val("").focus();
                    return false;
                }

            });
        });
```

now i want to pass data from select dropdown onchange function but this not working.

please help me.

Comment: `jQuery`version?... `.live()` is deprecated since 1.7, removed in 1.9

Comment: I am using jquery 1.8.3 but its working fine  but onchange loadData function is not working.

Comment: There is no function `search_author` in the code you have shown us.

Comment: you have to define all the functions you want to use outside of the document.ready block if you bind it in the select element directly. And I think you also need to declare the whole javascript above the `select` element, as otherwise the function will still not be declared for the JS compiler

Comment: From the code above we do not see your whole `<select>`. Are you sure you have defined it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem  is, that you declare the function `loadData` in the scope of the `document.ready` block.
That means it will only be accesbile from inside this block. To the outside world it does not exist.

You have to declare it outside. And I would also bind the event handler with jQuery, not directly in HTML

```
function loading_show(){
    $('#loading').html("<img src='img/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
}
function loading_hide(){
    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
}                
function loadData(page,profess){

    loading_show();                    
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_data.php",
        data: {page:page ,
               prof:profess
               },
           async: true,
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
            {
                loading_hide();
                $("#container").html(msg);
            });
        }
    });
   alert(page)  ; // working
   alert(profess)  ; //not working
}

    $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#profession').on('change', function () {
                  search_author($(this).val(), 'p_author');
                  loadData(1, $(this).val());
                });

                loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
                $('#container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
                    var page = $(this).attr('p');
                    loadData(page);

                });           
                $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
                    var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                    var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                    if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                        loadData(page);
                    }else{
                        alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                        $('.goto').val("").focus();
                        return false;
                    }

                });
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help now it getting the value from dropdown but not sending that value in load_data.php through ajax.please help me.

Comment: I do not know what you mean. The value is sent to the AJAX call. but if you need to process it, you have to to it in the success function. Withou the whole code I cannot help you more. You need to debug your problems, Try Firebug or the Chrome deveoler console, where you can see all the request and if they returned some data

Comment: please also upvote my answer if it works correclty.thanks

Comment: here is one problem when i select data from drop down it will send data but not sending the page value and gives error please give solution.Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: because you call `loadData('', $(this).val());` - here you have to set the page data you need instead of the `''`

Comment: yes now i use loadData(1,$(this).val()); now when i select data from drop down it will send data page=1 and dropdown value = some value but  when i click on pagination it will send page=2,3.. and dropdown value =blank

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look quite right:

```
onchange="search_author(this.value,'p_author'),loadData('',this.value)"
```

That comma between the function calls is likely a syntax error.  Your JavaScript console may even be telling you this.  In any event, you can solve that problem by not using inline JavaScript and just binding the `change` handler in your JavaScript code:

```
$('#profession').on('change', function () {
    search_author($(this).val(), 'p_author');
    loadData('', $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but this is also not working for me.

Comment: @user3410466: Define "not working."  Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  When you step through the code in a debugger, where does it fail?  How does it fail?